# Как разделить число на разряды?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы число делилось на разряды для цен?

```
function is_my_money($sum, $cz=2){
$sum = (string)$sum;
$sum = trim($sum);
$sum = str_replace(',','.',$sum);   
if ($sum) {
    $sum = round($sum,$cz);
    $sum = sprintf("%0.{$cz}F",$sum);
    $sum = rtrim($sum,'0');
    $sum = rtrim($sum,'.');

    return $sum;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

}

```
        $('#wsumm1').live('keyup',function(){
        var vale = $(this).val().replace(/,/g,'.');
        if (checknumbr(vale)) {
            goed_peremen(vale, 1);
        } else {
            $(this).parents('.changewoerr').addClass('err');
        }

        return false;
```

Comment: у вас про какой фрагмент кода вопрос вообще? Что вы ожидаете от этого кода, и что происходит?

Comment: вопрос про javascript или про php? Как связаны приведенные куски кода с вопросом и между собой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть готовые функции для таких задач

- https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php
- https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.money-format.php

Пример

```
$number = 1500000;
$number_formated = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
echo $number_formated; // 1 500 000,00
```